# Funcion switch para cambiar style de una variable?

Tags: javascript, html

como puedo cambiar el color de esta variable ? intente de todo ;(

```
var segundo = ["1", "2", "3"]
var span;
        span = document.getElementById("span").innerHTML;
    switch (segundo) {
    case "1":
        {

            span.innerHTML.style = "cyan";
            break;
        }
    case "2":
        {
            span.innerHTML.style = "Red";
            break;
        }
    case "3":
        {
            span.innerHTML.style =  "Yellow";
            break;
        }


}
```

Comment: La variable `segundo` es diferente a `"1"`, `"2"` y `"3"` ya que es un `Object Array`, en la estructura `switch` no se cumplirá la condición `segundo == "1"`, `segundo == "2"` ni `segundo == "3"`. Pero si `segundo[0] == "1"`, `segundo[1] == "2"` o `segundo[2] == "3"`.

Comment: Este código presenta muchos fallos, los cuales harán que lo que quieres no funcione. Además, sería bueno que editaras la pregunta para clarificar un poco el problema (p.e. una variable no tiene color que cambiar), qué hace ese código, cuál quieres que sea el resultado y explicar qué es lo que has intentado y porque no ha funcionado. Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro no son de ayuda al resto de usuarios. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] en el centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No se que quieres hacer realmente pero no puedes comparar un objeto array  con un valor como bien ha dicho el usuario *ftorres* , tienes que usar índices, no se lo que quieres hacer realmente pero normalmente en un switch tienes una variable normal que es la que colocas en la condición del switch y no no necesariamente un índice de un array.

```
    var segundo = "1"; //Puedes sacar el valor de un input
    var span;
    span = document.getElementById("span").innerHTML;
    switch (segundo) {
        case "1":
            {
                span.innerHTML.style = "cyan";
                break;
            }
        case "2":
            {
                span.innerHTML.style = "Red";
                break;
            }
        case "3":
            {
                span.innerHTML.style =  "Yellow";
                break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `style.background` para cambiar el color de un div

```js
var segundo = ["1", "2", "3"]
var span;
span = document.getElementById("span");
switch (segundo[0]) {
  case "1":
    {

      span.style.background = "cyan";
      break;
    }
  case "2":
    {
      span.style.background = "Red";
      break;
    }
  case "3":
    {
      span.style.background = "Yellow";
      break;
    }


}
```

```css
#span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="span"></div>
```

Comment: queria cambiar el color de la letra nomas no el fondo, lo arregle usando en case en ves de "1" usando el array por ejemplo 1

Answer (score 0):

No estas especificando la propiedad que cambia el color de texto, sino que estas cambiando el valor del objeto style cuando deberia de ser `elemento.style.color`. Cambien no puedes cambiar el color de texto de un `innerHTML` ya que es de tipo `String`, no `HTMLElement`. Tienes que eliminar todas las referencias a `innerHTML`.

Aqui tu codigo funcionando:

```js
var segundo = ["1", "2", "3"]
var span;
        span = document.getElementById("span");
    switch (segundo[0]) {
    case "1":
        {

            span.style.color = "cyan";
            break;
        }
    case "2":
        {
            span.style.color = "Red";
            break;
        }
    case "3":
        {
            span.style.color =  "Yellow";
            break;
        }


}
```

```html
<span id="span">
  <span>Texto</span>
</span>
```